# ASP.NET MVC Installer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, asp.net-mvc-2

We need to install ASP.NET MVC on several developers machines with VS2010. Unfortunately the only files I can find in the Microsoft Download Center are labelled as ASP.NET MVC installer for VS2008.

Can someone please point me in the direction of installer for VS2010, or can the VS2008 one also work for VS2010?

Thanks,
Dany.

Answer (score 1):

VS2010 comes with ASP.NET MVC 2 project templates already available out of the box.